# Get the date based on week number and day number using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the date in moment using week number and day number, for example, today is May 31, 2022 which is week 22:

```js
var weeknumber = moment("2022-05-31", "YYYY-MM-DD").isoWeek(); // returns 22
// 1 is monday and 7 is sunday
var weekdate = moment().day('7').week(weeknumber).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(weekdate); // returns "2022-05-22" 

// 1    2   3    4    5   6   7    // day number
// Mon Tues Wed Thur Fri Sat Sun   // day name
// 30  31   1    2   3    4   5    // date
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xypebn47/

The result of `weekdate` is not correct, start of the week is Monday and this Sunday is June 5, 2022 but it returns May 22, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your weekdate declaration to below.

```
var weekdate = moment().day('7').isoWeek(weeknumber).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Comment: that fixed it :P